# Can't connect to Radis server in node-client using Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, redis

I'm new to this field so, I will very much appreciate your help
I was trying to use *Redis* with my *VueJs* frontend project, and I installed *node-redis* npm package.
Also, I'm using Docker to try to point redis image with my docker node image.
But, I had got this error at my browser console:
 `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: net.connect is not a function`
[image]

This's **redis.js** file

```
const redis = require('redis');
const redisClient = redis.createClient();

(async () => {
  redisClient.on("connect", () => console.log("Redis Client connected"));

  await redisClient.connect();
  await redisClient.set("hello", "world");
})();
```

This's **vue.config.js** file

```
const webpack = require("webpack")

module.exports = {
    transpileDependencies: true,
    configureWebpack: {
        devtool: 'source-map',
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                process: 'process/browser',
                Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer']
            }),
        ],
        resolve: {
            fallback: {
                path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
                crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
                url: require.resolve("url"),
                net: require.resolve("net"),
                tls: require.resolve("tls"),
                util: require.resolve("util"),
                buffer: require.resolve("buffer"),
                Buffer: require.resolve("buffer"),
                assert: require.resolve('assert'),
                http: require.resolve('stream-http'),
                https: require.resolve('https-browserify'),
                stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
            },
        },
    },
    devServer: {
        allowedHosts: "all", // webpack v4 or higher
        compress: true,
        port: 80
    }
}
```

This's **package.json** file

```
{
  "name": "6lb-menu",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@diracleo/vue-enlargeable-image": "0.0.7",
    "@webzlodimir/vue-bottom-sheet": "^1.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "luxon": "^1.28.0",
    "masonry-layout": "^4.2.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "redis": "^4.3.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "vue": "^2.7.8",
    "vue-datetime": "^1.0.0-beta.14",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.27.2",
    "vue-inline-svg": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-lazyload": "^1.3.3",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.4.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.6.3",
    "vue-wow": "^1.2.0",
    "vuebar": "0.0.20",
    "vuetify": "^2.6.9",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0",
    "weekstart": "^1.1.0",
    "wicg-inert": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.8",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "sass": "^1.54.5",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "tls": "0.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "util": "^0.12.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.10",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

This's **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  # NPM service
  6lbui_npm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: node.dockerfile
    container_name: 6lbui_npm
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${LISTEN_IP}:${HTTP_NPM_PORT}:80"
    volumes:
      - ../app/:/usr/src/app:delegated
    networks:
      - network

  # Redis caching service
  6lbui_redis:
    image: redis:7.0
    container_name: 6lbui_redis
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 6379
    networks:
      - network

networks:
  network:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4: "${LISTEN_IP}"
```

Any suggestion if I walk in the correct way, instead of please suggest a way to use *redis* with my *VueJs client* project.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When connecting the client you need to tell it where to find the server:

```
const client = redis.createClient({
    socket: {
        host: '<hostname>',
        port: <port>
    },
    password: '<password>'
});
```

You can also check the [documentation](https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/references/client_references/client_nodejs/)

In your case, the server is `6lbui_redis` and the port is `6379` (can also be ignored for default value).